# JavaScript error (null or not an object) .Only in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, error-handling

```
var rows = [];
        for (var id in topics) {
            var topic = g_favoriteTopics[topics[id].id];
            var $row = $("table#Favorites tr#topicTemplate").clone();
            alert(topic.title);
            $row.find("td.txtCol a").html(topic.title);
            var href = commonVariables.formAction +
                "?PARTITION_ID=" + commonVariables.partitionId + 
                "&CONFIGURATION=" +  commonVariables.configurationId + 
                "&CMD=DFAQ&DFAQ_TOPIC_ID=" + topic.id +
                "&DFAQ_TOPIC_TYPE=" + topic.type;
            $row.find("td.txtCol a").attr("href", href);
            $row.find("td.imgCol input").attr("topicId", topic.id);
            rows.push(topic.title.toLowerCase() + "<<<>>><tr topicId=" + topic.id + ">" + $row.html() + "</tr>");
        }
```

The alert window shows the proper topic title (name of the topic).However Iam presented with a Javascript error (title is null or not an object),after the alert.
It runs fine in FF and chrome

Comment: does alert(topic.title); show you expected value in FF & Chrome ..?

Comment: What are the exact contents of the `g_favoriteTopics` and `topics` arrays? Everything below your `alert` is pretty much not useful info.

Comment: Is `topics` an array? If yes DO NOT use `for..in` to loop over its elements! Extending `Array.prototype` is not too uncommon and will break stuff when you loop using `for..in`

Comment: alert(topic.title) shows proper value in FF and chrome. This is an IE specific issue..I have written this code to print a list of topics and is working as expected in FF and chrome without any script errors.It has something to do with jquery compatibility in IE i guess. .Thanks